# Site-Packages in Python2.7 without VirtualEnv

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

When I use `pip install matplotlib --upgrade` it runs and installs `matplotlib` and all dependicies, and at the end reads `uninstalled version '1.3.1'`. Running python and `matplotlib.__version__` outputs `'1.3.1'` again, even though it was just declared uninstalled. How do I switch which python I'm running from, which would hopefully be where `pip` is installing and updating packages?

Edit: Running Mac OS 10.10.1, using python from bash.

`which pip` returns `/usr/local/bin/pip` and `which -a python` returns

```
/opt/local/bin/python
/opt/local/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

which I'm assuming is the problem. I've deleted 2.6 before, but my Mac uses it and I had to restore my OS. How do I switch amongst them.

Comment: What platform are you on? How did you install your Python? If your Python installation has `matplotlib` built in (in `dist-packages` or `Extras` or similar), removing it from `site-packages` may just mean you've re-enabled the built-in one. Try printing `matplotlib.__file__` and see what you get.

Comment: As far as "How do I switch which python I'm running from", that depends on your platform/shell/IDE/etc. For example, if you just type `python` at a bash shell on linux or Mac, it'll search your `$PATH` until it finds the first thing named `python`, while if you click the Run button in PyCharm it'll run the interpreter configured in your project settings, so there's no general-purpose answer to that.

Comment: matplotlib.__file__ returns `'/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc'`

Comment: whereas `which python` returns `/opt/local/bin/python`

Comment: Anyway, does `which pip` give `/opt/local/bin/pip`? Also, can you `which -a python` to see if you have any additional Python versions besides the MacPorts one and the pre-installed Apple one?

Comment: There appear to be many pythons installed. In the future I will use `vitrualenv`, and I understand the benefits. Is there a way to switch amongst them? Should I just trial and error which ones has the appropriate packages installed and adjust my `$PATH` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that you have two or more Python 2.7 installations, and the first `python` on the PATH comes from one installation (the MacPorts version, at `/opt/local/bin/python`), while the first `pip` on the PATH comes from a different one (you haven't said which, but I'd guess it's `/usr/local/bin/pip`, and it's attached to either the pre-installed Apple Python or yet another Python).

If you want to have lots of Pythons installed all over the filesystem and switch among them without using `virtualenv`, you just need to write some scripts with modify your `PATH`. (And your `PYTHONPATH`, if you use one… but hopefully you don't.)

But I wouldn't recommend that. If you want to use the MacPorts Python:

- Make sure you have the MacPorts `pip` installed (it should be in `/opt/local/bin/pip`). I don't know if MacPorts has a separate `python-pip` package, or expects you to [install it manually](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#install-pip), or otherwise.
- If you don't know how to rehash your shell cache, just open a new Terminal window after getting the MacPorts `pip` installed. Or, to be safe, just explicitly use `/opt/local/bin/pip` until the next time you logout and back in.
- When you write scripts, you may want to `#!/opt/local/bin/python` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env python`.
- Uninstall every other Python except the MacPorts one and the pre-installed Apple ones.
- Any packages you accidentally installed for other Python installations, just reinstall them for MacPorts. Also, you should usually check for ports first, like `port install python-ipython` or `port install python27-ipython`, and only fall back to `pip` if there is no portfile.

As a side note, many people who have this problem also have MacPorts colliding with Homebrew (or sometimes Fink, gentoo-alt, or other package managers, but none of them are very common nowadays). If you're using two such package managers, you really, really shouldn't be unless you know what you're doing. I'd disable one entirely (at least take it off your PATH, if not uninstall it). You will likely have to rebuild a bunch of stuff after you do so, but it's better than having a bunch of stuff that kind of sometimes works…